# .net regex optional named groups

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I want to parse input strings looking like this:

`client/02004C4F4F50/box/registration
client/02004C4F4F50/box/data/flow`

with the .NET regex libary. `client` and `box` are always the same but the rest may differ.
What I came up is this regex:

`^client/(?<id>.+?)/box/(?<type>.+)(/(?<value>.+)?)`

What I want is that `registration` and `data` are matched into the `type` group and that `flow` goes into an optional group `value`.
It should look like this:

```
Groupname | Input 1      | Input 2
---------------------------------------
       id | 02004C4F4F50 | 02004C4F4F50
     type | registration | data
    value | {empty}      | flow
```

But with my current solution the optional group (`value`) is never matched.
Perhaps someone has a hint.

Comment: Use this `^client/([A-Z \d]+)/box/(.+)` and split the last group with `|` for `data/flow` Demo [here](https://regexr.com/3mu78)

Comment: @AnkushRathi If OP could split, OP would not have asked for a regex solution. See *with the .NET regex libary*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This puts `registration` into the `value` group. But I see what you mean!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i see that, my bad

Comment: Do you mean you need [`^client/(?<id>[^/]+)/box/(?<type>[^/]+)(?:/(?<value>[^/]+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/mlpxBo/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I already fixed it to this. Thank you so much. I was blind....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match subparts using `[^/]+` pattern (any 1+ chars other than `/` char) and make the numbered capturing group rather than the `value` named capturing group optional, i.e. `(/(?<value>.+)?)` => `(?:/(?<value>.+))?` (also, you may turn the capturing group into non-capturing, or use [`(?n)` inline `ExplicitCapture` modifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#other) to make all capturing groups behave as non-capturing).

You may use

```
^client/(?<id>[^/]+)/box/(?<type>[^/]+)(?:/(?<value>[^/]+))?
```

See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eclient%2f%28%3f%3cid%3e%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b%29%2fbox%2f%28%3f%3ctype%3e%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%2f%28%3f%3cvalue%3e%5b%5e%2f%5cn%5d%2b%29%29%3f&i=client%2f02004C4F4F50%2fbox%2fregistration%0d%0aclient%2f02004C4F4F50%2fbox%2fdata%2fflow&o=m)

[image]